# Редирект со старых урлов в Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Переносим сайт с Magento на Битрикс. Задача стоит следующая: настроить редирект со старых урлов сайта на новые. Казалось бы, вроде, - ерунда, но в урлах с Magento идёт `site_name/index.php/cat_name.html`. Начинаю прописывать в `urlrewrite.php` таким образом:

```
array(
    "CONDITION" => "#^/index.php/([0-9A-Za-z\\_\\-]+)\\.html#",
    "RULE" => "OLD_URL=Y&NAME=$1",
    "ID" => "",
    "PATH" => "/"
)
```

По итогу вся эта беда игнорится и просто открывается главная страница. Параметры не передаются. Может лечится как-нибудь, кроме как переименованием основного файла `index.php`?

Comment: Что означает: "со старых урлов сайта на новые"? У вас домен сменился?

Comment: Ну так у вас написано `"PATH" => "/"` - какая же должна открываться страница? У вас в `index.php` есть обработка гет-параметров? Пробовали `"PATH" => "/index.php"`?

Comment: Нет, домен не сменился, но урлы будут другие.

Comment: Мне просто нужно было передать параметр, что это старый урл и все

Comment: PATH - мне, собственно, без разницы где это обрабатывать, путь особого значения не имеет

Comment: Дело просто в том, что параметра OLD_URL нету в REQUEST, он просто игнорирует строку и все

Comment: 404.php есть? mod_rewrite включен?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Длительные часы обсуждений и раздумий привели к тому что оптимального варианта сделать редиректы после переноса сайта на битрикс нет.

Для нескольких больших сайтов поступил следующим образом:

1. Сгенерировал на старом сайте таблицу массив старых адресов.
2. Дополнил на новом сайте массив новыми адресами страниц. Так как в моём случае требовалось сделать редирект на 100 тысяч товаров, то старые адреса страниц являлись ключами массива, а значениями были новые адреса.
3. Сохранил массив в отдельном файле так чтобы при подключении файла был доступен массив.
4. В init.php  подключаю файл и выполняю поиск в массиве по адресу. Если есть такой ключ, то делаю стандартный битриксовский редирект.

Вариант не самый хороший так как незначительно влияет на производительность, но если в остальном она в порядке, то и не критично. Зато получается достаточно быстро всё сделать и проблем в процессе никаких не возникает.

Через месяц-два просто удаляем подключение файла.